# How to know all the values from a column in a pivot table in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I created a pivot table just like this:

```
                                                     Mark
 Province        Student      Year       Subject       
'Barcelona'      'Martin'     2013      'Algebra'       8
                                        'Chemistry'     7
                                           ...         ...

                              2014     'Programming'    6
                              ...          ...         ...

                 'Sarah'      2013     'Programming'    5
                                        'Chemistry'    10
                                           ...         ...

                              2014     'Programming'    6
                              ...          ...         ...

                 'Luis'       ...          ...         ...
                  ....        ...          ...         ...
'Tarragona'       ....        ...          ...         ...

   ...            ....        ...          ...         ...
```

How can I get the names of all Barcelona's students? In other words, I would like to get:
[ 'Martin','Sarah','Luis',...]

Can somebody help me? Thank's!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df.query("Province == 'Barcelona'")['Student']
```

or

```
df.query("Province == 'Barcelona'")['Student'].tolist()
```

You may also want to `reset_index()` first if `Student` is part of MultiIndex (not a regular column):

```
df.reset_index().query("Province == 'Barcelona'")['Student'].tolist()
```

Comment: it doesn't work, it returns a KeyError. The only key that returns something is 'mark'. Do you know why? Thank you for trying to help me!

Comment: @trecnano, please provide an output of the following commands: `print(df.columns); print(df.index.names)`

Comment: print(df.columns) returns : Index(['mark'],dtype='object') ; and print(df.index.names) returns: ['Province', 'Student', 'Year', 'Subject']

Comment: Okey if I reset index it works; thank you! But if somebody know's an easiest way let me know please!